# Run a powershell command with arguments from the Run line

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am still learning PowerShell and the Windows run line seems to make it even harder

Question: How can I do this directly from the run line (if possible an admin powershell) but I can deal with clicking yes after the the download... it just slows down the process

```
wget 'https://MYSERVER/MYFILE.MSI' -O PROGRAM.msi; start PROGRAM.msi /qn
```

This works great when powershell is already open as admin, also works when powershell is open as normal user, but I have to wait for the program to be downloaded to click yes instead of clicking yes to the admin powershell and let the rest autoinstall.

I tried

```
Powershell -Command 'wget...
```

but not working

Answer (score 0):

Point of note: wget in PoSH is an alias

```
Get-Alias -Name wget

CommandType     Name
Alias           wget -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

... and with the way you are doing this, you are using wget.exe, not the above.
So, you can use wget.exe, but you have to specify the full UNC to wget.exe if it is not in your system path. That .exe is a must.

Or you need to remove the aliases

```
Remove-Item Alias:WGet
```

To download files from the web, look at the Invoke-WebRequest  examples

```
Get-Help -Name 'Invoke-WebRequest' -Examples
```

Or write your own function using .Net, someting like the below and put it in your PoSH user profile

```
Function New-ToolDownloadInstall ($url)
{
    # Set the webclient 
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

    # Extract the filename from the URL and Download 
    $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($url)
    $file = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\$filename"
    $webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)

    # Remove the web ADS
    Unblock-File -Path $file

    # Install the file
    Start-Process $file -NoNewWindow -wait
}

# Use the function
New-ToolDownloadInstall -url 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/1/5017D39B-8E29-48C8-91A8-8D0E4968E6D4/en/msoidcli_64.msi'
```

Here is another example
Download files from websites programatically via powershell
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/files-from-websites-4a181ff3

Also, some DOS level command have to be called this way, if you are in the PowerSHell_ISE.exe.

```
Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  &{ wget.exe 'https://MYSERVER/MYFILE.MSI' -O PROGRAM.msi; start PROGRAM.msi /qn }"
```

See more details here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters